# Problems extracting values from NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, crash, nsmutablearray, uilabel

I'm trying to parse data from a plist file into a NSMutableArray.

In my plist 
Root is a Dictionary containing an Array of 6 Numbers

I've created a label hooked with the IBOutlet UILabel *lbl4 object and I want this label to show the first element of the array made reading the plist. The problem is that the program crashes at the assigning instruction (the last one).
My code is this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"settings.plist"];

if(![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath]);
{
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"settings" ofType:@"plist"];
}

NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSString *err = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;

NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *) [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&err];
if(!temp)
{
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", err, format);
}

self.dataSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Dadi"]];
[lbl4 setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dataSet objectAtIndex:0]]];
```

The plist source code is the following:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Dadi</key>
    <array/>
    <key>D4</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>D6</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>D8</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>D10</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>D12</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
    <key>D20</key>
    <integer>0</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The Debug output says "2012-09-02 18:29:55.483 Faith[6014:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'"

Comment: What is the crash error message?

Comment: And, can you show the property list? (feel free to foo-ize any actual strings)

Comment: added plist and debug output to the question!

Comment: The "Dadi" array is empty. This is apparent because the `<array/>` tag is self-closing. You may need to restructure your plist so that the items that are intended to be in the array are actually in the array.

Comment: @warrenm You should post that as an answer! (it was an oversight on my part that the structure of the plist was not what OP desired)

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that there are *keys* associated with each NSNumber... not exactly implying that they are supposed to be inside the array (unless that was an erroneous error-quieting measure)

Comment: Yeah, that's why my comment was intentionally ambiguous; I noticed the other entries in the dictionary had keys, so they probably weren't what's intended to be in the array. At least, not without some significant restructuring.

Answer (score 1):

In your plist, the array stored at the dictionary's `Dadi` key is empty!

```
<key>Dadi</key>
    <array/>
```

So

```
self.dataSet = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[temp objectForKey:@"Dadi"]];
```

Sets self.dataSet to an empty array (i.e. even index:0 is beyond the bounds).

I would check for se.f.dataSet.count == 0 and provide a default in this case.

@warrenm mentioned in the comments that the structure of your plist is not what you might have expected. These are XML files, so any tag which ends with `/>` is "self-closing", and therefore always *empty*. To contain those numbers, you need to add an ending tag and place them inside:

```
<array>
  <integer>7</integer>
</array>
```

Of course, on further evaluation, your existing plist has keys associated with those, so this is possibly also not the right solution. You'll need to evaluate what your needs are for that plist.

Comment: I really don't know why, but it works now that i changed the plist source code in this (copied from a tutorial):

`{
 Dadi = (
  0,
  0,
  0,
 );
}`

Why now it works? It's not XML! What kind of plist is that and why it works?

Comment: That's JSON, not plist (thought they are almost 100% compatible). In JSON, {} implies object->NSDictionary, and () implies array->NSArray.